# No solutions with exponents in python sympy

Tags: python, sympy

When I run this program, I get no solution at the end, but there should be a solution ( I believe).  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  If you take away the Q from e2 equation it seems to work correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sympy import *

a,b,w,r = symbols('a b w r',real=True,positive=True)
L,K,Q = symbols('L K Q',real=True,positive=True)

e1=K
e2=(K*Q/2)**(a)

print solve(e1-e2,K)
```

It works if we do the following:

- Set Q=1 or,
- Change e2 to e2=(K**a)*(Q/2)**(a)

I would still like it to work in the original way though, as my equations are more complicated than this.

Comment: I expect the answer to be:

K=(q/2)^(a*a/(1-a))

Which is not defined when a=1.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3720 might be related?

Comment: Feel free to open an issue in the SymPy issue tracker about this. If `solve` doesn't find a solution and there is one, that's considered to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a deficiency of `solve`. `solve` is based mostly on heuristics, so sometimes it isn't able to figure out how to solve an equation when it's given in a particular form. The workaround here is to just call `expand_power_base` on the expression, since SymPy is able to solve `K - K**a*(Q/2)**a`:

```
In [8]: print(solve(expand_power_base(e1-e2),K))
[(2/Q)**(a/(a - 1))]
```

It's also worth pointing out that the result of `[]` from `solve` *does not* in any way mean that there are no solutions, only that `solve` was unable to find any. See the first note at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html.