# Sympy nsolve for simultaneous equation chemical equilibria

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to use Sympy's nsolve as a numerical method to solve reaction progress variables in simultaneous chemical equilibria. Unfortunately, for the present case no amount of initial guessing appears to arrive at a satisfactory solution. I believe this system does have a suitable solution where all four progress variables (the unknowns) have real solutions between 0 and 1.

Here is the simplified code:

```
from sympy import *
var('x1,x2,x3,x4')
P = 1.          # Pressure [bar]
n1 = 2.*x1      # x1 is progress variable for reaction 1
n2 = x2         # x2 is progress variable for reaction 2
n3 = 2.*x3      # x3 is progress variable for reaction 3
n4 = x4         # x4 is progress variable for reaction 4
n5 = 1.-x1-x2-3.*x3-2.*x4
nTot = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5

rxn1 = Eq(P*n1**2/(nTot*n5),3.06e-3)
rxn2 = Eq(n2/n5,8.02e5)
rxn3 = Eq(nTot*n3**2/(P*n5**3),1.07e21)
rxn4 = Eq(nTot*n4/(P*n5**2),8.25e14)

reactions = (rxn1,rxn2,rxn3,rxn4)
unknowns = (x1,x2,x3,x4)
answer = nsolve(reactions,unknowns,(1e-4,.1,.3,.2))
print (answer)
```

Here is the output from Sympy (I am using Sympy v1.1.1 in a Spyder3 environment with 64 bit Python 2.7):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-43632f4fa60f>", line 18, in <module>
    answer = nsolve(reactions,unknowns,(1e-4,.1,.3,.2))

  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 91, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2847, in nsolve
    x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 975, in findroot
    % (norm(f(*xl))**2, tol))

ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (1.1449e+42 > 2.1684e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.
```

I have attempted to use various solve (unsurprisingly, no analytic solution is available) and nsolve methods, none of which have thusfar been successful for this system of non-linear equations. I have also tried recasting the equations in logarithmic form with similar results.

Are there other solver settings that you recommend I attempt to employ?

Thank you for any assistance!
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the difficulty in finding a solution is due to the wide variation in magnitudes of the
constants.  For example, `rxn3` has a value on the right-hand side of
1070000000000000000000, while `rxn1` has a right-hand side of 0.00306.
Numeric algorithms often have trouble with equations with extreme floating-point
values.

Nevertheless, we can get somewhat close by symbolically solving the 4 equations
for `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4`. (Finding a solution in terms of the `n`-variables is
essentially the same as solving for the `x`-variables, but allows us to address
the main problem with fewer variables/equations).

```
soln = sym.solve([rxn1, rxn2, rxn3, rxn4], [n1, n2, n3, n4], dict=True)[0]
# {n1: -0.0553172667437573*sqrt(n5*nTot),
#  n2: 802000.0*n5,
#  n3: -32710854467.5922*sqrt(n5**3/nTot),
#  n4: 825000000000000.0*n5**2/nTot}
```

This gives us `n1`, `n2`, `n3` and `n4` in terms of `n5` and `nTot`. 
We can now attempt to solve the two remaining equations which define `n5` and `nTot` -- `rxn5` and `rxn6`, (see below) -- for `n5` and `nTot`.

Unfortunately, `sym.solve` fails to find a symbolic solution:

```
In [114]: sym.solve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot])
Out[114]: []
```

Note that when `sym.solve` returns an empty list it does not necessarily imply there are no solutions, [only that `sym.solve` failed to find one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191325/190597).

So let's try to find a numeric solution. Per [the docs for `sym.nsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve),

> mpmath.findroot is used and you can find there more extensive
>   documentation, especially concerning keyword parameters and
>   available solvers.

and the [docs for `mpmath.findroot`](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html) describe a `maxstep` parameter. By increasing the `maxstep` parameter, it turns out `sym.nsolve` can find a solution for `n5` and `nTot`:

```
In [148]: sym.nsolve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot], [0.5, 0.5])
ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (19920803.9870484600143 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.

In [149]: sym.nsolve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot], [0.5, 0.5], maxsteps=50)
Out[149]: 
Matrix([
[1.83437114233209e-8],
[  0.477964294180007]])
```

Now we can check if the solution makes sense:

```
import sympy as sym

P = 1.0          # Pressure [bar]
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, nTot = sym.symbols('n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,nTot', positive=True, real=True)
rxn1 = sym.Eq(P*n1**2/(nTot*n5),3.06e-3)
rxn2 = sym.Eq(n2/n5,8.02e5)
rxn3 = sym.Eq(nTot*n3**2/(P*n5**3),1.07e21)
rxn4 = sym.Eq(nTot*n4/(P*n5**2),8.25e14)
rxn5 = sym.Eq(n5, 1.0-(n1/2.0)-n2-3.0*(n3/2.0)-2.0*n4)
rxn6 = sym.Eq(nTot, n1+n2+n3+n4+n5)

soln = sym.solve([rxn1, rxn2, rxn3, rxn4], [n1, n2, n3, n4], dict=True)[0]
rxn5 = rxn5.subs(soln)
rxn6 = rxn6.subs(soln)

expr5 = rxn5.rhs - rxn5.lhs
expr6 = rxn6.rhs - rxn6.lhs
print(expr5)
print(expr6)
# -1.65e+15*n5**2/nTot - 802001.0*n5 + 0.0276586333718787*sqrt(n5*nTot) + 49066281701.3884*sqrt(n5**3/nTot) + 1.0
# 825000000000000.0*n5**2/nTot + 802001.0*n5 - nTot - 0.0553172667437573*sqrt(n5*nTot) - 32710854467.5922*sqrt(n5**3/nTot)

root = sym.nsolve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot], [0.5, 0.5], maxsteps=100)

# or using scipy.optimize.fsolve
# import scipy.optimize as optimize
# f = sym.lambdify([n5, nTot], (expr5, expr6))
# root = optimize.fsolve(lambda x: f(*x), [[0.5, 1e7]], xtol=1e-16)
# print('f({}) = {}'.format(root, f(*root)))

# or using bisect with verify=False -- mentioned in the `sym.nsolve` docs
# root = sym.nsolve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot], [0.5, 0.5], solver='bisect', verify=False)

print(root)
# Matrix([[1.64738651107199e-8], [0.530353285064842]])

root = {n5:root[0], nTot:root[1]}
nsoln = {var:val.subs(root) for var,val in soln.items()}
nsoln.update(root)
for var in [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, nTot]:
    print('{} = {}'.format(var, nsoln[var]))
for i, rxn in enumerate((rxn1, rxn2, rxn3, rxn4, rxn5, rxn6), 1):
    print('rxn{}: {}'.format(i, (rxn.lhs-rxn.rhs).subs(nsoln)))
```

which yields this solution:

```
n1 = 0.00000517060185532663
n2 = 0.0132120398187973
n3 = 0.0949735158684791
n4 = 0.422162542301846
n5 = 1.64738651107199E-8
nTot = 0.530353285064842
```

and these errors (differences between the left- and right-hand sides of the respective equations):

```
rxn1: -8.67361737988404E-19
rxn2: 0
rxn3: 131072.000000000
rxn4: -0.125000000000000
rxn5: -2.22044604925031E-16
rxn6: 5.55111512312578E-17
```

Note that while the absolute error for `rxn3` is rather large, the relative error is < 2e-16:

```
In [13]: 131072/1.07e21
Out[13]: 1.2249719626168225e-16
```

---

By the way, [the `sym.nsolve` docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve) also say:

> Note, however, that functions which are very steep near the root the verification of the solution may fail. In this case you should use the flag verify=False and independently verify the solution.

and

> One might safely skip the verification if bounds of the root are known and a bisection method is used:

```
In [155]: sym.nsolve([rxn5, rxn6], [n5, nTot], [0.5, 0.5], verify=False, solver='bisect')
Out[155]: 
Matrix([
[2.77113579502186e-9],
[2.83553974806881e-6]])
```

but this solution does not turn out to be quite as good as the solution found with `maxsteps=50` (or greater).

Comment: Unutbu: Thank you for your informative response. Is there a way to force the solution so that all unknowns are real and positive (negative solutions are not physically meaningful)? I suppose the converged solution will be strongly dependent on the initial guess and equation behavior - it would be nice to force a solution set within defined bounds for arbitrary dissimilar reaction constants. I will experiment with your recommendations and report back.

Comment: Yes, you can tell `sympy` that certain symbols are real and positive by setting it here: `n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, nTot = sym.symbols('n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,nTot', positive=True, real=True)`. I've update the post above accordingly.

Comment: `scipy.optimize` also has some minimizers, such as [`differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) or `fmin_cobyla` or `fmin_slsqp` which can search bounded regions. You might try experimenting with those to find a rough guess for the solution, and then use `sympy.nsolve` as a [solution polisher](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html) (search for "polishing").